# Entity Framework 7 Database First configuration (MVC 6)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

After a long constant struggle, finally figured out how to use EF7 Database first approach using MVC 6. This is how it goes:

App.Impl -> project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dnx451": { }
},
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
},
```

Then running the command from cmd:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=ip,port;Database=db;User Id=user;Password=pass;" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
```

3 problems I am facing with this. On my Impl project.

1. I have a folder dedicated to Data. My Data folder should contain all Database related things such as DbContext, DbClasses. However, Scaffold creates these files at the root. How can I specify the folder I want these files created?
2. At my work place, I could have a database with 50 tables. However, what if I only need access to 2? I don't want to add all 50 tables for my project. How can I specify which tables I want?
3. On my Database, I could have a table named "Users" because it is a table that contain users. However, scaffold should be creating a class as "User", since it is a single user until it becomes List. How can I specify the name of the table being created?

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: `-o Data` or `--output-dir Data` allows to specify output directory, `-t Users` or `--table Users` allows to create the class for one table Users. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Commands/Commands/Program.cs#L143-L226)

Comment: In regards to points 2 and 3, DB first tooling is still quite limited. I think these type of features are on the backlog.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold 
    "Server=Server\InstanceName;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer 
    --dataAnnotations
    --outputDir Data
    --verbose
    --table dbo.Users
```

All the above parameters should be in the same line, but I wrapped the long line to read it more easy. You can look at [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/7.0.0-rc1/src/EntityFramework.Commands/Commands/Program.cs#L142-L180) to see which options supports `scaffold` command in RC1.

Be carefully in copy and paste the `ConnectionString` from `appsettings.json` because you could have `Server=Server\\InstanceName;` in `ConnectionString`, but `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold` accept currently only `Server=Server\InstanceName;` and you will get **`System.InvalidOperationException` error** on the usage of `Server=Server\\InstanceName;` directly copied from the `ConnectionString` of `appsettings.json`.

Additional important parameter is `-p | --targetProject`, which is important if you use repository in the class library. In the case you defines `ef` command in the main project, and you start `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold` in the directory of the main project, but you use `-p` to reference the class library project.

The last remark. Sometimes one need to scaffold **subset** of tables from the database. It's not full clear from the command line help, but **one can specify `-t` (`-table`) parameter multiple times**. See [the note](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(October-1,-2015)#table-selection-in-reverse-engineering) in the EF7 wiki. Thus if you want to import only two tables `dbo.Users` and `dbo.Posts` (whether `Posts` have foreign key to `Users`) then you can use the following syntax

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold 
    "Server=Server\InstanceName;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer 
    -a
    -o Models
    -v
    -t dbo.Users
    -t dbo.Posts
```

**UPDATED:** One should use `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` instead of `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold` in ASP.NET Core RC2 and later.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. This answered most of my questions. As Shoe said, I guess the feature are still quite limited so i'll wait for an update and see if they implement a way to change name so I can make "Users" into "User" class.

Comment: @JohnC1: You are welcome! I hope too that one extend the possibility of `ef dbcontext scaffold` soon. I would like for example to be able to import some specific tables from the list (by for example `--table dbo.Users;dbo.Products;dbo.Orders`)

Comment: @JohnC1: I updated my answer by including how one can import multiple tables: `-t dbo.Users -t dbo.Products - t dbo.Orders`

Answer (score 1):

You can also reference your appsettings connection string. Let's say you have something like this in appsettings.json:

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=[DB SERVER];Database=[DATABASE];Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
 }
```

You can reference that connection string in your scaffolding command like this:

```
"Name=ConnectionStrings:Default"
```

Instead of like this:

```
"Server=[DB SERVER];Database=[DATABASE];Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to specify a handful of tables.
I followed Oleg's explanation for showing how to import multiple tables in one command.
But .Net Core 3.1, in the Visual Studio Package Manager Console, that way gives the error -
Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Tables' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".

So Oleg's syntax would have to be changed to -
t dbo.Users,dbo.Products,dbo.Orders

My full command was from the Package Manager Console is -

Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=usn;PWD=mypw;Connect Timeout=100" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f -t dbo.Users,dbo.Products,dbo.Orders