# Entity-framework-7 Organizing Fluent API configurations into a separate class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm familiar how to organize the fluent API configurations into a separate class on EF6, but how is this achieved with EF7?

Here is an example how to do it with EF6:

ModelConfigurations.cs

```
public class ModelConfigurations : EntityTypeConfiguration<Blog>
{
     ToTable("tbl_Blog");
     HasKey(c => c.Id);
// etc..
}
```

and to call it from OnModelCreating()

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelbuilder modelBuilder)
    {
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ModelConfigurations());
// etc...
    }
```

On EF7 I cant resolve the EntityTypeConfiguration? What is the correct way to implement fluent API calls from a separate class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-7-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration

Comment: I recommend you to use `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold` to generate Model from the *existing* database (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34457974/315935) for details). You will get many very good examples how to use fluent API in EF7 if you would get enough complex database as the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class BlogConfig
{
    public BlogConfig(EntityTypeBuilder<Blog> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        // etc..
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    new BlogConfig(modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I typically do for all my entity classes is provide a static method that gets called from my `OnModelCreating` method in my context implementation:

```
public class EntityPOCO {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public static OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) {
        builder.HasKey<EntityPOCO>(x => x.Id);
    }
}

...

public class EntityContext : DbContext {
   public DbSet<EntityPOCO> EntityPOCOs { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      EntityPOCO.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
}
```

Going a step further, you could even automate the process and generate the context class on the fly using attributes.  This way you only have to deal with the POCOs and never touch the context.

Comment: Attributes will go away with EF7

Comment: @Szer: source of your statement? Because I see that attributes/data annotations will be there (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap)

Comment: I was referring to .NET attributes, no EF data annotations.

Comment: @L-Three didn't know they've changed their mind. I was sure that they going to remove Annotations and leave only code-first way to model relationships.