# Fluent Api in Entity Framework 6 not compatible Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I had implemented Fluent API using Entity Framework 6. Have problems when implementing the same using EnityFrameworkCore.

Below is the code using Fluent API using EntityFramework 6

```
 public class CustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customers>
    {
        public CustomerConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Customers");
            Property(c => c.FirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(c => c.LastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(c => c.Gender).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(10);
            Property(c => c.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(25);
            Property(c => c.Address).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(c => c.City).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(25);
            Property(c => c.State).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(15);

        }
    }


  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductConfiguration());

            modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>()
           .HasRequired(c => c.Customers)
           .WithMany(o => o.Orders)
           .HasForeignKey(f => f.CustomerId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>()
                .HasMany<Products>(s => s.Products)
                .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
                .Map(cs =>
                {
                    cs.MapLeftKey("OrderRefId");
                    cs.MapRightKey("ProductRefId");
                    cs.ToTable("OrderDetails");
                });


        }
```

The issues that I am getting in EntityFrameworkCore are

1. It dosent recognize ToTable and Property keywords in CustomerConfiguration()
2. It dosent recognize Configurations, HasRequired,MapLeftKey,MapRightKey,ToTable keyword in OnModelCreating method

Could somebody tell me how to achieve this using Fluent API in EntityFrameWork Core

Comment: Look at the EF Core documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF core uses completely different APIs.So you must learn it first.

As an example : This is the way how it sets the `ToTable()`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .ToTable("blogs");
    }
```

To learn you have to read these links :

[**Table Mapping**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables)

[**Relationships**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

[**Creating a Model**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/)

**To encapsulate the configuration for an entity type in a class :**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public abstract class EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    {
        public abstract void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder);
    }

    public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void AddConfiguration<TEntity>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> configuration)
            where TEntity : class
        {
            configuration.Map(modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>());
        }
    }
}
```

You can see more details here (see the first post which was edited by **@rowanmiller** : [**Github**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2805)

Comment: So I cant create seperate configuration files and they add the configuration in onmodelcreating

Comment: you can refer this link.please let me know whether is that working or not ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855989/entity-framework-7-organizing-fluent-api-configurations-into-a-separate-class

Comment: As far as I can see you can't. The issue for `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>`  still open: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2805

Comment: Thanks for the link.EF team has given workaround for that.please see my post @BotondBalázs

Comment: Looks great! I don't understand why they haven't included it in the framework itself.

Comment: Yes.may be due to they have more critical issues (500+)  on git :D @BotondBalázs

Comment: Is anyone having the same issue in that ToTable is missing. Using Core 1.1 Class Project and EF 1.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

direct link to [table maping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables) documentation.
Read the rest of it as well.  EF core is a new product not an upgrade to EF6.