# Database First but only a subset of the database

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am creating an asp.net6 web application that will pull back transactional data from an existing database. Inside the database we have a lot of lookup tables that I don't have a need for. I am able to import the database with `ef dbcontext scaffold` but I get all the tables in the database. Is there a way to pick and choose the tables I want? I can delete all the lookup tables but if I ever have to update any of them and I use the `ef dbcontext scaffold` will it pull all the tables again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. I searched a long time for the solution of the problem in the past. The options of `ef dbcontext scaffold` are documented not good enough. The solution as the using `-t` parameter **multiple times**:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold ... -t dbo.Users -t dbo.UserPosts
```

I described the usage of `ef dbcontext scaffold` more detailed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34457974/315935). It includes the reference to [the Design Meeting Note](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(October-1,-2015)#table-selection-in-reverse-engineering).

**UPDATED:** Starting with .NET Core RC2 one should use [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) instead of `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold`.

Comment: As a follow up I am getting a couple of issues with some tables. One is no primary key on the table, which is what it is. The other does not specify the table. Is there away to get more information in the output?

Comment: @JamieBabineau: I suppose that some tables which you imports have references to another tables which you not yet imports. You should look at the foreign keys of the imported tables. Just add more tables with `-t` switch and I hope the problem will be solved.

Comment: my particular issue is `Unable to interpret the string 0 as a SQLServer string literal.' but looking at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3861 it still creates the object it just won't default it.

Comment: @JamieBabineau: It seems to be new very specific problem, which is independent from your originally asked question. Could you open new question and include details of the exact schema of your database (your can generate the script). I can try to help you only if I could reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For EF Core 2.0, you should do:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Connection String" -Povider "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" -OutputDir Models -Tables "Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "TableN"
```