# Entity Framework Core creating model from existing database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reverse-engineering, scaffolding

With Entity Framework Core, how do you generate the EF model and the entities?

According to [ASP.NET Core - Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) Microsoft article you need to run a command like this one in the Package Manager Console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

That gives you zero control on what tables or views to import. Is it possible that this is the only way to reverse engineer the database and create the EF models and entities now with EF Core and how is that progress when compared to the way this was done with full Entity Framework for years now?

Comment: Part of your question answers your main question: "How do you generate..[...]" - you pasted it in your question. There was an existing VS extension called Entity Framework Power Tools, but it looks like it's not been updated to work with EF Core yet. Which convention are you used to that lets you pick which objects you want generated?

Comment: @MarkC. With full Entity Framework you are presented with a list of database objects you can select from when you create a new Entity Data Model (edmx file).

Comment: Add the tables argument (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we Scaffold DbContext from selected tables of an existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065769/can-we-scaffold-dbcontext-from-selected-tables-of-an-existing-database)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to do that in Entity Framework Core.
Read the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features

Comment: Wow, there's a lot missing... so why would anyone want to use this crippled ORM called EF Core? Is cross-platform the only advantage/incentive to use EF Core?

Comment: Actually you have control over the imported tables, take a look at the Scaffold-dbContext documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell 

you have the -Tables parameter where you specify all the tables that you want to import, here is an exemple :

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(October-1,-2015)#table-selection-in-reverse-engineering

Comment: @Bouam Once you go through that do you still get the edmx UI where you can view and edit database objects and fields and see the relationships between your tables?

Comment: What if you want to import a SQL server view, not a table? #micdrop

Answer (score 83):

I know this question is a bit old, but I think it's pretty useful for people stumbling over the same problem.

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to specify which Tables should be generated.
It should be possible if you add the `-Tables` Parameter to the command.

Here is the command I used to generate 3 Tables of the Database (in Package-Manager Console):

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;"  
     -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
     -OutputDir Models -Context NorthwndContext 
     -Tables Products,Categories,Suppliers -Force
```

As you can see, I use the Northwnd-Database and only generate the tables "Products, Categories and Suppliers". Obviously, you can add more tables, you just have to separate them with commas.

If you don't know, you can get the DatabaseName by going to the Data Connections (Server Explorer), click on the Database you want to add and on the right side (Properties), you see a Property (Name). For me it was "NORTHWND.MDF".

I used `-Force` to override any Models I've already created.

You can use `-DataAnnotations` to get annotated models.  Otherwise, you get Fluent model configuration.

PS: I've only tried this with ASP.NET Core 2 and Entity Framework Core 2.0.0.

Comment: Thanks, I just think it's ludicrous to go from full featured edmx UI that allows you too view and edit the tables, relationships, fields and so on to some command line tool and tout that as ground braking progress...

Comment: I don't know what crack MS has been on lately.  Core solves the problem of running .Net on non IIS servers...a problem by 1% of IT shops that run MS, and if the idea catches on the need for Windows servers wanes...as a business plan I don't get it.

Comment: @HiHo I copied your code and ran in the package console nothing happens however earlier the same worked for .net core 1.1 and I recently upgraded to core 2.0 with ef as well and I am unable to update models.  (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap) they says **We will do our best to complete or at least make good progress on these:**

Answer (score 16):

Those who want to convert Sql database schema to EF core using dotnet core follow the steps:

Run all the commands one after one (first command for those who want to create a new project else you can ignore that and just run other given commands from your project root folder)

```
dotnet new mvc -o <ProjectName>

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

Finally...

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=servername\instancename;Database=My_Database;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

This will create the necessary models and context of your db schema inside the models folder of your project.

Now easily you can generate **CRUD** code by applying the following command :

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name <MyNewController> -m <ModelName> -dc <MyDbContext> --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries
```

Change the **MyNewController** with your desired controller name , **ModelName** with the  model name inside the models folder that you want to target and finally **MyDbContext** with the system generated context file name available inside the Models folder

but before run that command make sure you have made the necessary changes at your  **appsettings.json** and **startup.cs** file inside your project folder

**appsettings.json** add after the line

"AllowedHosts": "*",

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbConnection": "Server=servername\\instancename;Database=My_Database;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

**startup.cs** file add just before the line

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

```
services.AddDbContext<SwiftRbs_LocalContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));
```

Enjoy!!

Comment: `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=<server>;Database=<Database>;User Id=<user>;Password=<password>" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models` worked for me. Curious as to why this got a down vote?

Comment: The final command `dotnet ef...` command failed. Found help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070108/1521988)

Answer (score 13):

My situation was that I had a .net 4.5+ class library with DbContexts in it.

Those DbContexts had been created from an existing DB using the "Code First from existing Database" Wizard. This Wizard seems to be missing from EF Core.

**To create a new Code First DbContext from an existing DB compatible with EF Core**, I loosely followed the guide [here](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database)

My steps:

- Created a new Core Class Library
- Added the nuget package *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore*
- Added the nuget package *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools*
- Added the nuget package *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer*
- Added the nuget package *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design*
- Opened the nuget Package Manager console
- Entered the [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell)

  ```
  Scaffold-DbContext "data source=MYSQLDBSERVER\MYSQLINSTANCE;initial catalog=MYDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  ```
- Entered as provider

  ```
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
  ```

Please note that when using a non-Core project you might run into problems with the nuget Package Manager console. I avoided this problem by just creating a new Core Class Library, instead of a .net one.

Once you have created the context, you can edit it like normal in Code First, e.g. you can delete the tables you don't want to use.

Comment: +1 for **creating a new Core Class Library, instead of a .net one.** .Net 4.x project throws `FileNotFoundException` on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

Comment: They are all .NET, I think you mean using a .NET Core class library instead of a .NET Framework class library.

Answer (score 3):

You can also apply the cheater's method: Open VS2015, create a new class lib with the same name as the actual project, and then run the Entity Data Model Wizard.

Once your done, copy and paste into your .net core project.  There is a bit of tweaking required of the resulting code, but it's trivial.

However, running the scaffold command as above is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Scaffold DbContext from existing MS SQL database**

Was facing issue in VS 2022 and dotnet7 and below solution is worked for me

1. Install below 4 packages in API/MVC/WEB/Console application and rebuild application

   *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version 7.0*

   *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 7.0*

   *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --version 7.0*

   *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 7.0*
2. Run below command in Package Mnager Console:

   **Note**: give proper data source , db name, id and pwd in connection string

   Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=db_name;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=true;User Id=sa;Password=*****" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
3. **If any error occurs make sure that 'TrustServerCertificate=true' property present in connection string
   and restart visual studio and try scaffold command again**

   I tried multiple attempts by points 1) and 2) but it was failing but when I applied 3) point as well it worked for me