# .NET Core Entity Framework many to many relation same entity (related products)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to built a related items type model using Entity Framework in my .NET Core 1.1 MVC application. I keep running into the following error (tried all combinations of deletebehaviours with foreign keys):

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_MenuItemRelation_MenuItems_RelatedMenuItemId' on table
>   'MenuItemRelation' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

Before I go and simply use a mapping table, I would like to hear the community input on this.

#### Model builder

```
        //MenuItem <> MenuItem many to many (related item) mapping
        modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemRelation>()
             .HasKey(mr => new { mr.PrimaryMenuItemId, mr.RelatedMenuItemId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemRelation>()
             .HasOne(mr => mr.PrimaryMenuItem)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(mr => mr.PrimaryMenuItemId);

         modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemRelation>()
             .HasOne(mr => mr.RelatedMenuItem)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(mr => mr.RelatedMenuItemId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

#### Domain model

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrls { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuItemRelation> RelatedItems { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

#### Mapping Entity

```
public class MenuItemRelation
{
    public MenuItem PrimaryMenuItem { get; set; }
    public long PrimaryMenuItemId { get; set; }
    public MenuItem RelatedMenuItem { get; set; }
    public long RelatedMenuItemId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, if you delete a `MenuItemRelation`, you want to delete the `MenuItem` in `RelatedMenuItem`, too? Do I understand the last line of Model Builder correctly? (not too familiar with EF code first)

Comment: If so, what would prevent this from happening: `MenuItemA => RelationAB => MenuItemB => RelationBA => MenuItemA`. Now if either `RelationAB` or `RelationBA` is deleted, then everything would get deleted, right?

Comment: All in all, this seems weird. I'd understand, if you delete a `MenuItem`, then all `MenuItemRelations` that use this as either primary or related foreign key should be deleted. That's a clear, non-cyclic path. But deleting a referenced `MenuItem` whenever a `MenuItemRelation` is deleted, would cause all kinds of cyclic deletion extravaganzas. -- (you delete one relation which causes an item to be deleted, then another relation (or several) could become invalid and has to be deleted, which causes another item to be deleted and so on and so forth)

Comment: I think I did not explain well enough. What I would want to happen is that I cannot delete a menuitem if there are related menuitems there. So I would need to first clean all related items before I can remove the menuitem. I first had default settings (which is cascade) and tried any other combination, but nothing is accepted.

Comment: Both `MenuA` and `MenuB` relate to `SubMenuX`. You delete `RelationAX` and suddenly `MenuB` has lost its relation, because `SubMenuX` is deleted...

Comment: Ah, okay. But for that, a simple `FOREIGN KEY` constraint should suffice. The `ON DELETE` stuff basically says "if I'm going down, I'll take all of you with me."

Comment: Yes but that would not be an issue. If I have menuitem a related to b and menuitem c related to a, I would not want to be able to remove menuitem c, before I removed relationab and relationac.

Comment: Yes and I think that is what I had :) I have added the ondelete restrict on both FKs, it does not matter

Comment: Okay, so what happens if you simply remove the ondelete stuff? You shouldn't be able to delete a `MenuItem` that is "used" by a `MenuItemRelation`.

Comment: Well like I said... I tried every combination of FK contraint and both FKs. There must be something else. Or maybe it is not even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I modeled the desired SQL outcome and reverse engineered the many to many relationship by using database first approach as explained here [Entity Framework Core creating model from existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705235/entity-framework-core-creating-model-from-existing-database). The result is below.
Basically it just required me to add both the incoming relation as well as the outgoing relation on the menuitem class.

Feel free to comment if there are better ways of doing this.

#### Table TSQL

```
Create TABLE MenuItem(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(max)
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

GO

CREATE TABLE MenuItemRelation (
    PrimaryMenuItemId int,
    RelatedMenuItemId int,
    PRIMARY KEY (PrimaryMenuItemId, RelatedMenuItemId),
    FOREIGN KEY (PrimaryMenuItemId) REFERENCES MenuItem (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (RelatedMenuItemId) REFERENCES MenuItem (ID)
)

GO

Insert into dbo.MenuItem values ('MenuItemA')
Insert into dbo.MenuItem values ('MenuItemB')
Insert into dbo.MenuItem values ('MenuItemC')

GO

INSERT into dbo.MenuItemRelation values (1,2)
INSERT into dbo.MenuItemRelation values (1,3)

GO

DELETE from dbo.MenuItem where ID = 1

GO

//Confirmed no cascading happens
```

#### Domain model (with some naming edits)

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrls { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuItemRelation> RelatedItems { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuItemRelation> RelatedTo { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

#### Mapping object

```
public class MenuItemRelation
{
    public MenuItem PrimaryMenuItem { get; set; }
    public long PrimaryMenuItemId { get; set; }
    public MenuItem RelatedMenuItem { get; set; }
    public long RelatedMenuItemId { get; set; }
}
```

#### Model builder

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemRelation>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.PrimaryMenuItemId, e.RelatedMenuItemId });

modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemRelation>()
    .HasOne(d => d.PrimaryMenuItem)
    .WithMany(p => p.RelatedItems)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PrimaryMenuItemId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemRelation>()
    .HasOne(d => d.RelatedMenuItem)
    .WithMany(p => p.RelatedTo)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RelatedMenuItemId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```