# Creating a .NET Core web api that has a route access to an existing Database

Tags: c#, .net, api, entity-framework-core

Currently I am reading some documentations on creating web API using the Database first approach. I noticed that most of the tutorials migrate their table on their application. How do I make an web api that only expose or has one route to expose the table in a specific database using Entity Framework that no need data migration?

Comment: 1.  It's not quite clear what you are asking about  2. Remove any requests for documentation/tutorials/sample code.... just ask what you want to know / How to do what you want.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I made some edit. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: you probably want   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705235/entity-framework-core-creating-model-from-existing-database

Comment: If you don't want to use the data migration feature, then don't use it. You don't have to. I've never used it.

Comment: The question is still very unclear. Expose one table, database first, migrations.

Comment: @GabrielLuci If its okay , may I know how you do it? Most of the tutorials and documentations only do data migration feature.

Comment: @dropoutcoder Its basically like I want to create a web api using .net core, this api will access the table. The problem is most documentantion for database first migrate the whole data of that table. I dont want to do that since i got thousands of data. I just want to access it for developing a mobile application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to download 4 from nugets and run Scaffold-DbContext command. Download these 4 from nugets.

1) EntityFrameworkCore

2) EntityFrameworkCore.Design

3) EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

4) EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Open Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. And enter this below in console.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourserveraddress;Database=yourdatabase;user id=youruser;password=yourpassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: I only need one table. I think this will automatically create the other tables in the database.

Comment: You just can remove all unwanted entity classes .cs and remove all unwanted tables from DbContext.cs if you want to use only 1 table.

Comment: It didn't create other tables in the database. It only create entities classes .cs and DbContext in your web api project based on your existing database.

Comment: I am testing it right now. I'll delete the other models created and remove other context. How will I know if it works and was able to connect to the table?

Comment: DbContext will connect to your table. Eg, your table is UserLogin 

1) Add this in your api function => 
var db = new YourDBContext(); 
var s = db.UserLogin; 
2) Put breakpoint at code line after "var s = db.UserLogin" 
3) Call api function through Postman or URL and see if your "s" has list or not (when your UserLogin table has data)

Comment: I have done sample document for you. Can check https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BVr-yqlTkvvdE8m_ZNrFlHwwsmLkB9OzjzYhqH-LjUI/edit?usp=sharing to understand better.

Comment: I encounter an error while running the app. InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'NETCoreWebApiDemo.DBTestContext' while attempting to activate 'NETCoreWebApiDemo.Controllers.SampleController'.

Comment: did you google for this error? need to see all your codes.

Comment: I got it now. I add the connectionstring in the ConfigureServices in the startup.cs. Im currently testing.

Comment: Ok. hope everything fine soon.

Comment: I encountered an error while debugging. 1. Error = Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. 2. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data but when I continue the compiler without debugging I was able to see raw data in my browser. JSON file was still loading but its working now. You are very patient on me. Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: I know this might be old. But do you perhaps have an idea how to apply pagination on this core web api? The api results too many data. Because of that I cant generate the JSON file.

Comment: You mean show 10 records only with selected page number? context.YourTable.Skip(PageNumber * 10).Take(10);

Comment: Yep. 10 or 50. I cant generate the whole json. Maybe just a simple request query string.

Comment: You can use this code I typed.

Comment: Where should I add it? In the startup.cs?

Comment: in your api function where you get data from database.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you are trying to create all the classes based on your existing database.

This is done with the [`Scaffold-DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) command. You can use it manually as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705235/entity-framework-core-creating-model-from-existing-database), but I prefer to use the [EFCorePowerTools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki) plugin. Use the [Reverse Engineer](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering) feature, which will generate and run the appropriate `Scaffold-DbContext` command for you.

Comment: Will this create a multiple models for different tables automatically? I only need a single table.

Comment: Ill give it a try. Thanks Gabriel.

Comment: You can pick which tables to create classes for.