# Scaffold-DbContext from package manager console is giving a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I have started to face this issue just recently. I'm using the Visual Studio 2022 Preview latest. I made a few simple changes to the DB and used the validation tool in dbForge Studio 2022 for SQL Server to validate all objects. The DB is valid.

When I try to update my context, I get the following output.

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.TransformText()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.ProcessTemplate(ITextTransformation transformation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.GenerateModel(IModel model, ModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I get a successful build, but it immediately fails with the error. I'd like to research this, but no other log windows show any errors, and I cannot figure out what is causing this.

Comment: I think the source for `TransformText()` can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Design/Scaffolding/Internal/CSharpDbContextGenerator.cs#L30)... but good luck trying to determine what could be null in this method.  Looks like the blame for the file reveals _some_ changes were made to it within the last few months, so maybe something is broken in it.  Might be worth logging an issue on that GitHub repository.

Comment: This severely misses a [mre]. Check that all tools and packages are updated to the latest version.

Comment: @GuruStron cannot do a minimal as this happened because there was no change except for some simplification in DB. If `Scaffold-DbContext` is a part of `dotnet-ef`, it has been updated. I'm on the `7.0.0‑rc.2.22472.11` Project, Nugets, EF, .Net and the dotnet-ef

Comment: I thought a `datetime2` was the cause, but that is still not it. Is there a way to get some more debug dump to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much aimless struggle, I finally decided to go undo my schema changes one by one and the moment I deleted this table from the DB, scaffolding started to work normally again:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LookupImportBrand] (
    [CompanyId] BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    [BranchId]  BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]      [dbo].[Name250] NOT NULL,
    [Active]    [dbo].[Boolean] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_LookupImportBrand_LookupImportCompany] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LookupImportCompany] ([Id])
);
```

I cannot pinpoint whats the root cause here but I recreated the table and all is well.

Comment: Could it be that you added a table with no primary key? That what the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 10):

It happens because of missing `PK`.

You have 2 options to manage this problem:

1. Discover the table that don't have `PK` by using the script (in SQL):

```
  select tab.[name]
  from sys.tables tab
  left outer join sys.indexes pk
  on tab.object_id = pk.object_id 
  and pk.is_primary_key = 1
  where pk.object_id is null
```

and add them `PK`

2. Generate `EF` without the tables that don't have `PK`
   by using this script (in SQL)

```
 SELECT name
 FROM sys.tables
 where name in ( 
    select tab.[name] 
    from sys.tables tab
    left outer join sys.indexes pk
    on tab.object_id = pk.object_id 
    and pk.is_primary_key = 1
    where pk.object_id is not  null
)
```

then you [can Scaffold DbContext from selected tables of an existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065769/can-we-scaffold-dbcontext-from-selected-tables-of-an-existing-database)

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting point.

Answer (score 4):

ok - it seems this is a known issue with EFCore 7.0.0, see [Github Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29516)

It's caused by a missing Primary Key on a table.  I found one of my tables had the PK missing, I added one and the dbcontext scaffolding then succeeded.

Comment: I rolled back to EFCore 6.0.11 and scaffolding succeeded

Comment: You can  use EF core 6.0.13 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore#versions-body-tab

Answer (score 2):

With Entity Framework Core 7.0.2 . Find list of tables what has not Primary key

```sql
SELECT 
    schema_name(tab.schema_id) AS [schema_name], tab.[name] AS table_name
FROM 
     sys.tables tab LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes pk ON tab.object_id = pk.object_id AND pk.is_primary_key = 1
WHERE 
    pk.object_id IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    schema_name(tab.schema_id), tab.[name]
```

then add primary key.

Or use Entity Framework Core 6.x .

Comment: what happens with intersect tables that do not need a PK? I have a load of those and I don't want to have to create PKs on all of those

Comment: In Entity Framework Core 7.0.2 (current version) table must have PK. Wait about 16 days more, in Entity Framework Core 7.0.3 no need PK. Intersect table that do not need a PK, you join use keywords `JOIN` and `WHERE foo.X = bar.X` as normal.

Comment: What a joke! The NHibernate system I'm migrating from did this 10 years ago! I recommended EF and this is making me look like an idiot

Comment: Or wait to Entity Framework Core 7.0.3 after about 15 more days. It is a bug.

Comment: Apparently not a bug. I received a working configuration from a Microsoft engineer on the EFCore git repo. I posted my problem and solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186741/entity-framework-7-many-to-many-intersect-table-skip-navigation-problem/75247297#75247297

Comment: I also did the same think with you. Wait about more 14 days to Entity Framework Core 7.0.3 you no need this action.